# why does java 11 no longer allow macos app's

Tags: java, macos, dock

since some 6 years I have wrapped JAVA programs into an .app
in order to be able to start a program from the macOS dock.
Suddenly, since JAVA 11.0.1 the app seems dead. Construct:

'xyz.app' directory,

'Contents' subdirectory, in there:

'Java' directory with xyz.jar and library.jar,

'MacOS' directory with 'JavaAppLauncher',

'Resources' directory with xyz.icns (icon),

'Info.plist' and 'Pkginfo';

The only files modified since years are the .jar's

Does anybody know if the meta-files inside the .jar's need
a different content?

;JOOP!

Comment: A lot has changed in Java 11. Have you tried running the jar file directly?

Comment: Yes, without any problem.

Comment: I did some tests and now I'm certain that the 'JavaAppLauncher' is the cause. It may be too old; as long as I don't have to change the application in the app I can have it working with an older library.jar; as my app's are only bootstraps for large applications from the Dock, I rest my case. Thanks for reading. ;JOOP!

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the repo here: https://github.com/federkasten/appbundle-maven-plugin.git, then fix it accordingly to work on Java 11.